# when rendering their project the video size became distorted, resulting in stretched visuals despite the frames being perfectly rendered

Tags: render, blender, hdrimages

I was diligently working on my project, meticulously crafting each frame to perfection. However, when it came time to render the final product, I encountered an unexpected issue. For some reason, the video size went completely awry. While the frames appeared to be perfectly rendered, upon converting the project into a video format, everything became stretched beyond recognition.[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyyFD.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6wZp.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkLDW.png)